# Apache Kafka-Exception : org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/List;)V

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Apache Kafka version kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0

During Poc i have created simple producer and consumer.
When i am try to consume message getting following error :

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/List;)V
at com.spnotes.kafka.simple.Consumer$ConsumerThread.run(Consumer.java:59)
```

Code :

```
package com.spnotes.kafka.simple;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Consumer {
    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] argv)throws Exception{
        if (argv.length != 2) {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s <topicName> <groupId>\n",
                    Consumer.class.getSimpleName());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String topicName = argv[0];
        String groupId = argv[1];

        ConsumerThread consumerRunnable = new ConsumerThread(topicName,groupId);
        consumerRunnable.start();
        String line = "";
        while (!line.equals("exit")) {
            line = in.next();
        }
        consumerRunnable.getKafkaConsumer().wakeup();
        System.out.println("Stopping consumer .....");
        consumerRunnable.join();
    }

    private static class ConsumerThread extends Thread{
        private String topicName;
        private String groupId;
        private KafkaConsumer<String,String> kafkaConsumer;

        public ConsumerThread(String topicName, String groupId){
            this.topicName = topicName;
            this.groupId = groupId;
        }
        public void run() {
            Properties configProperties = new Properties();
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
            configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "simple");

            //Figure out where to start processing messages from
            kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configProperties);
            kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
            //Start processing messages
            try {
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                        System.out.println(record.value());
                }
            }catch(WakeupException ex){
                System.out.println("Exception caught " + ex.getMessage());
            }finally{
                kafkaConsumer.close();
                System.out.println("After closing KafkaConsumer");
            }
        }
        public KafkaConsumer<String,String> getKafkaConsumer(){
           return this.kafkaConsumer;
        }
    }
}
```

Ruining using command :

```
java -cp .:/home/osboxes/Kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/libs/*:/home/osboxes/Kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1/libs/KafkaAPIClient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.spnotes.kafka.simple.Consumer test group1
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at com.spnotes.kafka.simple.Consumer$ConsumerThread.run(Consumer.java:59)
```

Comment: KafkaConsumer.subsribe(java.utils.List) is 0.9.0 API. Check the client version you are using to make sure 0.10.* is used.

Comment: I am using  kafka clients-2.2.0 Iam facing same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using wrong API thanks for amethystic .
After adding new client version it's start working

Old API was in POM

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Added new API in POM

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

No backward compatibility between Kafka API old and new version

Comment: @ShrJoshi this happens even in the case where you have more than one version of Kafka installed in your cluster. Best way to tackle this scenario is to specify below command in shell.


export spark kafka version=<Version number>

e.g: export spark kafka version=0.10